# Remove stopwords using multiprocessing python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Removing stopwords is a standard NLP task. If we have N texts, how can I use multi processing in Python to, given a **common** list `stopwords` remove stopwords in parallel from the N texts? Normally one does something like

```py
stopwords = ["...", ...]. #whatever list of stopwords here

def remove_stopwords(text):
  return [w for w in text.split() if w not in stopwords]
```

If we were to do multiprocessing, we would need to copy on each process `stopwords`. This is an expensive task, as copying would take much more time than executing `remove_stopwords`. How can I have all the processes access a shared instance of the Python list `stopwords` so that I don't have to spend time copying?

This is what I tried. The shared memory array actually spends a lot of time (I have never been able to complete this computation):

```py
import random
import time
import spacy
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Array
from ctypes import Structure, c_wchar_p
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Word(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('text', c_wchar_p)]

chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzáéíóúñABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ"

def generate_vocab(n_words, char_mean=8, char_std=3):
    words = []
    for x in range(n_words):
        k = max(1, round(random.gauss(char_mean, char_std)))
        word = "".join(random.choices(chars, k=k))
        words.append(word)
    return words

def get_texts(n_texts, n_words, vocab):
    return [" ".join(random.choices(vocab, k=n_words)) for i in range(n_texts)]

def remove_stopword(doc, sw):
    return " ".join([token for token in doc.split() if token not in sw])

vocab = generate_vocab(500)
trial_texts = get_texts(5000, 500, vocab)
stop_words = vocab[:30]
common_stopwords = Array(Word, [(word,) for word in stop_words])

st = time.time()
clean_texts = [remove_stopword(doc, sw=stop_words) for doc in trial_texts]
print(time.time()-st, "to clean them in series")

def rm_stopword_usual(doc):
    remove_stopword(doc, stop_words)
    
def rm_stopword_shared(doc):
    remove_stopword(doc, common_stopwords)
st = time.time()
with Pool(processes=8) as p:
    clean_texts = p.map(rm_stopword_usual, trial_texts)
print(time.time() - st, "to clean them in parallel copying stopwords")
st = time.time()
with Pool(processes=8) as p:
    clean_texts = p.map(rm_stopword_shared, trial_texts)
print(time.time() - st, "to clean them in parallel with shared stopwords")
```

The partial output that I get is

```
1.2284278869628906 to clean them in series
0.3515629768371582 to clean them in parallel copying stopwords
```

Comment: I don't see a question related to a specific technical issue here.  Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @itprorh66 If we have N texts, how can I use multi processing in Python to, given a common list stopwords remove stopwords in parallel from the N texts?